# How can i get dynamic site without ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic, fadeout

I find this script:
http://perishablepress.com/demos/slide-fade-content/
But this script is with ajax. Pages loaded with ajax don't display jquery. How can I get script without ajax, changing display:none to block in css. I use this

```
<div id="galeria">
<a  class="showSingle" target="1">Motocykle</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="2">Auta</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="3">ATV/quady</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="4">Łodzie</a>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv"  style="display: block;"></div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv" style="display: none;"></div>
      </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
       var item = $(this);
       var vis = jQuery('.targetDiv:visible');
       var targetItem = item.attr('target');
       var target = jQuery('#div' + targetItem);
       var fn = function() {
           target.fadeIn('slow');
       };
       if (vis.length) {
           if (vis[0].id == "div" + targetItem) {
               fn = function() {};
           }
           vis.fadeOut(fn);

       } else {
          target.fadeIn(slow);
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

but it doesn't look like this: http://perishablepress.com/demos/slide-fade-content/

Comment: can you make it a jsfiddle to demonstrate what the problem is?

Comment: What does "don't display jquery" mean?

Comment: The target syntax is : <a target="_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename">. So your target names point to a frame that you haven't include to your html code. I wouldn't recommend use frames. You can use id's

Comment: The demo uses AJAX, but the color fade plugin doesn't depend on it. I think you can use `.colorFade()` with any DIV after calling `.fadeIn()`.

Comment: Siply: what can I get this:http://perishablepress.com/demos/slide-fade-content/ withaut ajax(http://api.jquery.com/load/ "Script Execution"..."If .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed."- therefore I can not use ajax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `target.fadeIn(slow);` to `target.fadeIn('slow');`

http://jsfiddle.net/gg3S6/1/

Comment: Why `vis.size()`? .length is just fine with jquery objects.

Comment: @KevinB yep, it's not necessary, I always use `size()` on jQuery, but `length` also works

Comment: Ok it is fine. But when I click the same class ("showSingle") once again, the content of div is disappear. I dont want this.